# How to dynamically submit form input values with OnChange event using JQuery in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I'm currently developing a simple true odd finder calculator using python, django and jquery. I need to have `form input submit actions executed by jQuery` as the user types in the input values. The goal is to get rid of `submit buttons` in the frontend html. As of nowadays calculator based web applications don't require submit buttons. The functionality behavior should look like [here](https://oddsjam.com/betting-calculators/vig). I did a research and found out that i need to use JQuery. After implementing the functionality in my app, am able to type the first form input element, however upon clicking the second form input so as to start typing, my application crashes with `server error 500`, if i go back then type the second form input, it updates output.

How can i implement form input onChange using jquery to match the referenced functionality above.

My template and JQuery code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Two Way True Odd Finder{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<script type="text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.form-control').change(function () {
        
          $('#myform').submit();

      });
     
  });
</script>



    <div class="container m-5">

      <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Dashboard Home</a>

      <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="btn btn-primary">3  Way True Odds Finder Calculator</a>

        
    </div>



<div class="container m-5 text-justify">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <form action="" method="post" id="myform">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="Odd1" class="form-label">Odd 1</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="odd1" id="Odd1" min=" " value=" " step=".001" required='required'>
            </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Odd2" class="form-label">Odd 2</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="odd2" id="Odd2" min=" " value=" " step=".001" required='required'>
          </div>
         
          <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>-->
          
        </form>
  
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
                
  
       

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Results</h5>


                <table class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">#</th>
                      <th scope="col">Odd1</th>
                      <th scope="col">Odd2</th>
                      
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Initial Odds With Juice</th>
                      <td>{{HomeOdd}}</td>
                      <td>{{AwayOdd}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Implied Probability Win %</th>
                      <td>{{Home_implied_probability}}</td>
                      <td>{{Away_implied_probability}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">True Odds Without Juice</th>
                      <td class="text-success">{{Home_True_Odd}}</td>
                      <td class="text-success">{{Away_True_Odd}}</td>
                    </tr>
                 
                  </tbody>
                </table>

              

                <div class="container text-justify">
                  <p>Total Implied probability is {{TotalImpliedProbability}}%</p>
                  <p>Inverted probability is {{Inverted_Probability}}%</p>
                  <p>Bookie juice is {{Juice}}%</p>
                  <p>True probability is {{True_Probability}}</p>
                  
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
              <div class="card-body">

                <h5 class="card-title">Enjoyed the calculator?</h5>

               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    

      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container bg-light p-5">

      <h3>HOW IT WORKS</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
    
      
{% endblock %}
```

django view

```
def two_way_calc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        odd1 = float(request.POST.get('odd1'))
        odd2 = float(request.POST.get('odd2'))

        func_def = odd_finder_true_2(odd1, odd2)

        context = {
            'Juice': func_def['Juice'],
            'TotalImpliedProbability': func_def['TotalImpliedProbability'],
            'HomeOdd': func_def['HomeOdd'],
          
            'AwayOdd': func_def['AwayOdd'],
            'Home_True_Odd': func_def['Home_True_Odd'],
           
            'Away_True_Odd': func_def['Away_True_Odd'],
            'True_Probability': func_def['True_Probability'],
            'Home_implied_probability': func_def['Home_implied_probability'],
            
            'Away_implied_probability': func_def['Away_implied_probability'],
            'Inverted_Probability': func_def['Inverted_Probability'],
            }
        return render(request, 'three_way_temp.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'three_way_temp.html', {})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('two_way_calc/', views.two_way_calc, name='two_way_calc'),
   
]
```

Python function behind the calculation

```
def odd_finder_true_2(first_odd, second_odd):
    home_implied_probability = round((100/first_odd), 2)
    away_implied_probability = round((100/second_odd), 2)
    
    total_implied_probability = home_implied_probability + away_implied_probability
    
    
    inverted = (100/total_implied_probability) * 100
    
    juice = total_implied_probability - inverted

    hundred_odd_home = total_implied_probability/home_implied_probability
    hundred_odd_away = total_implied_probability/away_implied_probability
    prob_true = 1/(round(hundred_odd_home, 2)) + 1/(round(hundred_odd_away, 2))
    
    my_dict_two = {
        'Juice': round(juice, 2),
        'TotalImpliedProbability': round(total_implied_probability, 2),
        'HomeOdd': first_odd,
        'AwayOdd': second_odd,
        'Home_True_Odd': round(hundred_odd_home, 2),
        'Away_True_Odd': round(hundred_odd_away, 2),
        'True_Probability': round(prob_true, 1),
        'Home_implied_probability': home_implied_probability,
        'Away_implied_probability': away_implied_probability,
        'Inverted_Probability': round(inverted, 2)

    }
    
    
    return my_dict_two
```

Answer (score 0):

so there are a few things that i should say before your answer

First of all it's better approach to use AJAX instead of `submit` your form because AJAX prevents the page from being reloaded and by using it you do not need to send a whole complete http request and receive a complete response
It will only send needed information to server and get exact answer and js helps you to inject that data in your page

Second you don't actually and necessarily need jQuery, you can do what you want in pure js using fetch API however jQuery is an option too

**Now the answer**

5xx Errors are server side errors and thank to you for sending your complete code i can show you error

So the problem is when you trigger `submit` event, you are changing one input and this causes your form to be submitted,

**BUT, WHAT ABOUT SECOND INPUT?**

it has no value and thus your server can't do the calculations right

**How to fix this?**
It's up to your algorithm, if you can find a default value to be set on the second input, it can solve the probe
Or
You can check it in you jQuery code

```
$(".form-control").on("change",function(){
    if($("Odd2").value !== "") 
        $('#myform').submit()
}) ;
```

Also The jQuery code you've write is correct but it can be better

You are using `change` event which fires after the value is changed AND when user left the input (`blur event`)

You will get a better and more **live** result using `input` event

```
$(".form-control").on("input",...)
```

===============

Updated, based on your last comments, my guess was right and you want the answer to be shown to the user immediately after he entered the number
So you need to use another event called `input` here's the result (you can add a simple `alert` before that `if` to see how `input` event fires

```
$(".form-control").on("input",function(){
    if($("Odd2").value !== "") 
        $('#myform').submit()
}) ;
```

Let me know if your code is changed a lot and provide me your new jQuery code if this didn't solve your problem

============
Updated

Again my guess was right and you need to prevent page from being reloaded (or redirected) this can be done by AJAX

you have multiple choices in AJAX

you can use pure JS (xmlHttpRequest object)

you can use Fetch API in js

you can use Axios.js which is a great library designed to handle Ajax requests and responses

Or finally you can use jQuery

Because in your project you are already using jQuery, I'll do it using jQuery but i don't approve it, Fetch is best option in my opinion, anyway :

```
$(".form-control").on("input",function(){
    if($("Odd2").value !== "") 
        var fData = new FormData($('#myform'));
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'AddressToYourBackendFile', 
            method : 'POST', 
            data : fData
        });

        jqxhr.done( res => {
             console.log('your response is ready :\n' + res);
        });
}) ;
```

Comment: Hi @Mahdiar, have changed the code to match your snippet, however, still the `server error 500` is persisting, immediately i click the second input field to start populating value.

Comment: I have added a little bit of trick to your snippet to make it get past the `server error 500`, however the output is not displayed until i click somewhere outside the form inputs. The goal is to have the output displayed automatically when typing second input value.

Comment: Yes like i said that's because of  ```change``` event, it fires AFTER user has left the input, you can use ```input``` event instead of it, or set a timer inside of your handler, ```input``` event is a better option,, and please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Comment: Hi @Mahdiar, still i'm unable to have the content displayed automatically after user leaves second input field. Kindly let me know if u checked the link i shared on desired display behavior. Thanks

Comment: Well the input event is the answer, I Just saw the link, I'll update the answer using ```input``` event

Comment: Hi @mahdiar, after updating the code using your updated code, `the form allows me to type only one digit in the second input` then it submits automatically, displays output automatically. In other words, i'm unable to type the entire value for second input field.

Comment: Yes i knew this problem will happen and this is why i suggested you to use AJAX, I'll update the answer using ajax and leave the choice to you, you have two options : 1-use regular forms like your doing now and add a submit button 2-use AJAX to prevent page from being reloaded

Comment: Thank you, i will through it, however the goal is to have button-less form, user will only be required to type the input values then have results displayed automatically.

Comment: Yes i knew you don't want any button, AJAX is what you need, BUT remember ajax response is different than the old forms, you need to send back Only Necessary Information from your server now(not an entire html page) in response of that request and also if the answer is more complicated than a single value, you should transfer it into ```JSON``` notation and then send it back from server to client, after it you can use ```JSON.parse( jsonOBJ) ``` inside ```done``` function to use that answer in your front app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244355/discussion-between-bernietechy-and-mahdiar-mransouri).